# OpenStack launching instance error

Tags: cloud, openstack

I'm trying to launch an instance of Ubuntu in OpenStack, but I'm getting this error:

> **"Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance , the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: Build of instance  aborted: Block Device Mapping is Invalid.]"**.

I've tried this: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/62636/instance-creation-fails-block-device-mapping/ but none of the answers seem to work in my case.

What could I do?

Comment: Which version of OpenStack you're using? Also let me know the Ubuntu version.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava I'm using the latest version of Packstack OpenStack and Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (cloud image).

Comment: So you have freshly installed OpenStack-Newton or just updated?

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick that I did recently.

1. SSH into the openstack `controller` or `cinder node`
2. cd into /var/log/cinder
3. tail volume.log  `//I used yad --tail though;)`

Read the last lines of the log file (I assume you dint try spinning any VM’s since this error was received.)

The last line will look something like this:

> ERROR *****: Image *****: Error message

Hope this helps you to find the **actual error** and solve it.

**UPDATE: Error: No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available**

I would suggest to  tail logs before powering on the Instances. Something like

```
( tail -f /var/log/nova/* | grep -i error
```

Probably the problem is with space on your server. Open the `/etc/nova/nova.conf` file and replace (also try to change the value of `cpu_allocation_ratio/disk_allocation_ratio`):

> **ram_allocation_ratio=1.5** (probably 0.0 in some cases) to **ram_allocation_ratio=3**

Than restart the services:

> sudo service openstack-nova-scheduler restart
>
> sudo service openstack-nova-conductor restart

Also have a look [here](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/91041/no-valid-host-was-found-there-are-not-enough-hosts-available/).

If you are running everything on a virtual machine, set `virt_type=qemu` in /etc/nova/nova.conf ([libvirt] section) as [this post](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/54025/error-in-creating-instances-no-valid-host-was-found/) says.

Comment: Thanks to you I've realized that I was using an incorrect volume size (1GB vs 10GB), but now I'm getting this error "Error: Failed to perform requested operation on instance "Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS", the instance has an error status: Please try again later [Error: No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available]."